# require() failed but ether not returned?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm looking at [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd536b5fbaf0ba64b71b6ebc87d9647fa9a09053dc6533d0d281a48939615bcb9), where 0.01 ether is sent to the `ExchangeETHforTokenMannual()` function from [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x048c2eb8dfb1eb5dcf7ecfef9cf027ba85ea6cf7).

You can tell from the contract code (line 244) that there is a `require()` call enforcing a minimum amount of 0.081 ether. Since the transaction only sent 0.01 ether, in theory, the require call should fail and all state changes should be undone (including the 0.01 ether sent); however, the transaction shows up as successful.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The field `minContribution` is 0.001, not 0.081.
Check it here:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x048c2eb8dfb1eb5dcf7ecfef9cf027ba85ea6cf7#readContract

Comment: That's strange, how does this reconcile with the `uint256 public minContribution = 81000000000000000;` on line 102?

Comment: And the transaction didn't end up transferring any tokens to the address that sent the ETH?

Comment: On line 290 there is a function `updateTokenContribution` which could change `minContribution`;

Comment: The transaction did modifying balance of msg.sender on line 238. You can check balance through reading contract on function `balances(address)`.